# How to filter and group the data based on name using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, grouping

I have the following list of descriptions which belong to each name. Please let me know how can I group or list the descriptions per name.

html:

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="nameGroup in loopData"> <!-- this ng-repeat should be available as per my requirement -->
        <div ng-repeat="loopData in nameGroup.values track by $index" ><!-- this ng-repeat should be available as per my requirement -->

    <!-- {{loopData}} -->
        <div class="text-center merged">{{loopData.name}}</div><!-- ng-if="$index === 0" -->
        <div class="text-center">{{loopData.description}}</div> 

     </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.finalLoopData = {};

  $scope.loopData = [{ "country":"Abc", "id":"001", "mynumbers":[], 
    "values": [
      {"description": "first desc", "name": "First Test Name"},
      {"description": "second desc", "name": "First Test Name"},
      {"description": "third desc", "name": "First Test Name"},
      {"description": "fourth desc", "name": "Second Test Name"},
      {"description": "fifth desc", "name": "Second Test Name"},
      {"description": "sixth desc", "name": "Third Test Name"},
      {"description": "seventh desc", "name": "Third Test Name"},
      {"description": "eighth desc", "name": "Third Test Name"},
      {"description": "ninth desc", "name": "Third Test Name"},
      {"description": "tenth desc", "name": "Third Test Name"},
      {"description": "eleventh desc", "name": "Fourth Test Name"},
      {"description": "twelfth desc", "name": "Fourth Test Name"}
    ]
  }];

  $scope.arrayToObject = function () {
    var finalLoopData = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.loopData[0].values, function (value, key) {
        //console.log(value);//gives all value objects
        if (!finalLoopData[value.name]) { 
             finalLoopData[value.name] = new Array();
             //console.log("name: "+value.name);//First Test Name //Second Test Name //Third Test Name //Fourth Test Name
        }
        finalLoopData[value.name].push(value);
    });
    $scope.finalLoopData = finalLoopData;
  }
  $scope.arrayToObject();
});
```

If I run this code, I am getting individual description with names, but not with group names, here is my expected output is similar to below:

**First Test Name**

- first desc
- second desc
- third desc

**Second Test Name**

- fourth desc
- fifth desc

**Third Test Name**

- sixth desc
- seventh desc
- eighth desc
- ninth desc
- tenth desc

**Fourth Test Name**

- eleventh desc
- twelfth desc

Created [Filter](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/268zbkeg/21/):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

If you can not change the loops in the template, consider the following:

**Template**

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- Original loops -->
  <div ng-repeat="nameGroup in loopData">
    <div ng-repeat="loopData in nameGroup.values track by $index">

      <!-- Data name -->
      <strong>{{loopData.name}}</strong>

      <!-- Loop data descriptions -->
      <ul ng-repeat="description in loopData.descriptions">
        <li>{{description}}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.loopData = [
    {
      country: "Abc",
      id: "001",
      mynumbers: [],
      values: [
        { description: "first desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "second desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "third desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "fourth desc", name: "Second Test Name" },
        { description: "fifth desc", name: "Second Test Name" },
        { description: "sixth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "seventh desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "eighth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "ninth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "tenth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "eleventh desc", name: "Fourth Test Name" },
        { description: "twelfth desc", name: "Fourth Test Name" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  this.$onInit = function() {
    $scope.loopData.forEach(function(data) {
      const groupedValues = {};

      // group values by name
      data.values.forEach(function(value) {
        // initialize name group
        if (!groupedValues[value.name]) {
          groupedValues[value.name] = {
            name: value.name,
            descriptions: []
          };
        }

        // add description to name group
        groupedValues[value.name].descriptions.push(value.description);
      });

      // update values
      data.values = Object.values(groupedValues);
    });
  };

});
```

Note that the `$onInit` function will convert `$scope.loopData` to the following:

```
[
  {
    "country": "Abc",
    "id": "001",
    "mynumbers": [],
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "First Test Name",
        "descriptions": [
          "first desc",
          "second desc",
          "third desc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Second Test Name",
        "descriptions": [
          "fourth desc",
          "fifth desc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Third Test Name",
        "descriptions": [
          "sixth desc",
          "seventh desc",
          "eighth desc",
          "ninth desc",
          "tenth desc"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Fourth Test Name",
        "descriptions": [
          "eleventh desc",
          "twelfth desc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

### Original answer

In your html you're not looping on your processed `finalLoopData` variable. Also, to display the name of the group once, you need to have it in the first loop (not the second).

Consider the following code:

**Template**

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- Loop final data -->
  <div ng-repeat="nameGroup in finalLoopData">

    <!-- Group name -->
    <strong>{{nameGroup.name}}</strong>

    <!-- Loop group descriptions -->
    <ul ng-repeat="description in nameGroup.descriptions track by $index">
      <li>{{description}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.finalLoopData = {};

  $scope.loopData = [
    {
      country: "Abc",
      id: "001",
      mynumbers: [],
      values: [
        { description: "first desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "second desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "third desc", name: "First Test Name" },
        { description: "fourth desc", name: "Second Test Name" },
        { description: "fifth desc", name: "Second Test Name" },
        { description: "sixth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "seventh desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "eighth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "ninth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "tenth desc", name: "Third Test Name" },
        { description: "eleventh desc", name: "Fourth Test Name" },
        { description: "twelfth desc", name: "Fourth Test Name" }
      ]
    }
  ];

  this.$onInit = function() {
    const finalLoopData = {};
    $scope.loopData[0].values.forEach(function(item) {
      // initialize name group
      if (!finalLoopData[item.name]) {
        finalLoopData[item.name] = {
          name: item.name,
          descriptions: []
        };
      }

      // add description to name group
      finalLoopData[item.name].descriptions.push(item.description);
    });

    // apply results
    $scope.finalLoopData = finalLoopData;
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and solution, but as per my requirement, I need to use my first ng-repeats as it is, on top it I need to get my desired output.If I use the above, then my existing functionality breaks. You can see in my html code post as they are available.

Comment: I've update the answer to preserve the loops in your initial template.

Comment: Thanks for your help and solution. It helped me a lot really. Sorry for my late response.